# Search a list of strings between two values

Tags: c#, string

I have an alphanumeric `List<string>` that I need to return all strings between two user enter values.  So for example lets say the string is made up with the following values;

```
100F
50F
aa1
SR100
SR9
abc
```

So if the user enters in values of `ab` and `z` the following would be returned;

```
abc
SR9
SR100
```

How do I do this?

Comment: sounds like a job for if, > and <

Comment: I don't understand your example?  Is it searching backwards?  Why does the `z` cause it to sop at `SR100`?

Comment: @GrantWinney Because `aa1` < `ab`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would compare each item in the list with the start and end using [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public IEnumerable<string> PerformSearch(List<string> list, string start, string end)
{
    return list.Where(i => 
        i.CompareTo(start) >= 0 &&
        i.CompareTo(end) < 0);
}
```

To get the results in the order you specified (it's not clear if the order is important), you'd have to then order the results alphabetically.

It's also not clear if you want to *include* or *exclude* the "end" value-- this code will exclude it, but if you change the `<` to `<=` you'll have an inclusive search.

**Example**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHXqXG

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` :

```
List<string> values=.....;
string lower="ab";
string upper="z";

var matches=values.Where(s=>string.Compare(s,lower)>=0 && s.Compare(s,upper)<=0);
```